# Остановить цикл while

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу понять как остановить цикл `while`, создал массив из 5 ячеек с `Random` и теперь если меняю в ячейке 2 значение на 1, то цикл не останавливается, то есть мне нужно остановить цикл если во всех ячейках одно значение 1.

```
int count[] = new int [5];
count[0] = 1;
count[1] = 1;
count[2] = 0;
count[3] = 1;
count[4] = 1;`

Random rand = new Random(); 
int ran = rand.nextInt(count.length);


while(count[ran] >= 1) {
    ran = rand.nextInt(count.length);
    Log.d("", "count "+count[ran]);
}
```

Comment: > остановить цикл если во всех ячейках одно значение 1 — вроде можно так: `while (!Arrays.stream(count).allMatch(x => x == 1)) { ...`

Comment: что не так , где метод .allMatch() он подчеркнут красным

Comment: а, извините, вместо `=>` должно быть `->`

Comment: а где Х , что должно быть?

Comment: Enjo Flash да просто вбейте в гугл как цикл while использовать. Вы не правильно его понимаете

Answer (score 1):

Написать доп. функцию, которая проверяет массив на единицы:

```
boolean isOnes(int[] arr){
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
       if(arr[i] != 1)
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

И использовать:

```
while(!isOnes(yourArr)){
   //do someth
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну, как-то так.

```
boolean allOnes = false;
int countOnes;
int count[] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
Random rand = new Random();

int ran = rand.nextInt(count.length);

while(!allOnes) {
    countOnes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if (count[i] == 1) countOnes++; 
        ran = rand.nextInt(count.length);
        Log.d("", "count "+count[ran]);             
        if (countOnes == count.length) allOnes = true;
    }
}
```